# Web host with godaddy but have Squarespace run user side

Tags: android, mysql, web-hosting, squarespace

If I already have my domain setup with Squarespace but want to use the domain for web hosting also, let's say with GoDaddy can I do this? I just want the web hosting accessibility for my android app to access MySQL data, but the actual site on Squarespace won't need to access any of the data on GoDaddy or the database. So can I sign up for GoDaddy with my domain and use it for MySQL but leave my domain with Squarespace so when someone tries to access my site it take them there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sign up for a domain, you need to select authoritative name servers for your domain.  If you define two A (host) records on those name servers, for example godaddy.mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com, then you can refer to your Godaddy server for MySQL and your Squarespace server for hosting your website.